# FreeForm app on mac and incosistent connection line arrow behavior

Tags: ventura

I cannot figure out how connection line arrows work, when to use Start and End.

Here you can see 3 connections to Help | Feature Request | Bug

[image]

With Help I had to use Start to put arrow in a correct place

[image]

For the other two had to use End

[image]

I cannot figure out how these work and its driving me crazy.
Initially I thought it was doing this based on the order in which I selected items, but no. Then I though order in which they were created, but still no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the relative positions of linked objects.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! but this is so weird, why would they do this :) thoughts?

Comment: I don't know why, but it makes sense in LTR writing system. We perceive something to be "next" when it's on the right or below ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

When a line is placed on the diagram it appears to regard the direction as left to right. So, without reshaping the line, start is left, end is right.

Try setting end to an arrow, and then drag the endpoint to the 'to' object, and drag the un-arrowed start to your 'from' object. For your connections which are right to left you would need to drag the arrows around such that the direction of the line is reversed. Note you'd only need to do this if you were really concerned enough about your arrow heads matching the internal settings of the line.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I will do. I hate inconsistencies.